# Android: При установке APK не добавляется иконка в меню

Tags: android, android-studio, menu, icon

Здравствуйте!

Я совсем недавно начал изучать программирование под `Android`
и пользуюсь `Android Studio`. Свои приложения я тестирую в основном на своём смартфоне. В последнее время, когда я тестирую свои приложения **в главном меню смартфона не появляются их ярлыки**, хотя приложение установлено в системе. Попробовал запустить приложение на эмуляторе, проблема повторилась.

Пришел к выводу что в `Android Studio` есть какая-то настройка скрывающая ярлыки для установленных приложений.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Вот мой манифест.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.mysite.appname">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.vk.sdk.VKOpenAuthActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="vk0000000" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AppNameActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <data android:scheme="vk0000000" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

**Обновление**

Сейчас проверил, и убедился что при создании новых проектов, все отлично - ярлыки добавляются. Значит или что-то в настройках проекта не так, или намудрил с цифровыми подписями. Надеюсь кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой!

Comment: Покажите ваш манифест. Уверен, что проблема именно там

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я нашел ответ! Проблема была в манифесте.
Необходимо было сделать так:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="vk0000000" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Ответ был найден здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698772/android-apk-icon-is-not-being-installed

Про intent-filter можно почитать здесь: http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/64-urok-26-intent-filter-praktika.html

**Update от модератора**

В общем тема в том, что запускающий/главный тег `intent-filter` должен быть отделен от остальных `intent-filter` - совершенно очевидно, что это баг Android'а

Comment: Расскажем модератору, почему это нельзя считать багой? :)